# Doesn't automatically jump to different characters in both buffers

Tags: scrolling, ediff, zooming

Emacs 27.1

I want to find differents between 2 buffers.

I use command *ediff-buffers*

Steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Type the *n* in the *Ediff Control Panel*
[image]

Again Type the *n* in the *Ediff Control Panel*
[image]

**And because the line is longer than the width of the window**
I need manually by mouse to scroll in the first buffer to see what exactly is different.
Also I need manually by mouse to scroll in the second buffer to see what exactly is different
[image]

As you can see it doesn't automatically jump synchronously to different characters in both buffers.

Comment: That's what happens here. Are you typing the `n` in the `Ediff Control Panel`?

Comment: What @NickD said. `C-h m` to learn about Ediff - or check its manual.

Comment: @NickD Yes, I typing "n" but it not help

Comment: You have to type the `n` in the `Ediff Control Panel`: that's a separate frame that pops up when you start the `ediff` process. Typing it randomly somewhere else will have no effect on the `ediff` buffers (although it may modify whatever other buffer was occupying the window in which you typed the `n`).

Comment: @NickD I was updated post

Comment: So IIUC your complaint is that since the line is longer than the width of the window, Emacs does not automatically scroll *horizontally* to pinpoint the difference (but once you get there manually, the difference is presumably made visible by the highlighting). `n`  is irrelevant for this purpose.

Comment: @NickD yes,  the line is longer than the width of the window

Comment: @Drew I was update my post.  The line is longer than the width of the window. Maybe this is a resason of problem.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do what you want: there are a few synchronized scrolling modes, but AFAIK, they affect vertical scrolling only. Maybe you can set `truncate-lines` to `nil` (or perhaps enable `visual-line-mode`)  to get the whole line displayed without scrolling.

Comment: What is it that you want to happen? The data has lines that are **much** wider than your windows, so you need to scroll to see all of a line. *The same line can have a diff at the far left and a diff at the far right.* What do you expect Emacs to do, to show you what you want to see in such a case? Note that you can shrink the text size using `C-x C--`, which will show you more of the line in the same window. But your lines are **very** wide.

Comment: @Drew When I'm scrolling by mouse, maybe is it possible for the both buffers too scrolling horizontally at the same time? It will be very convenien